# Android Maps SDK not getting current location

Tags: android, google-maps

I am trying to display a users current location using the google map activity. when the activity is launched the google map is displayed as it should be, but there is no marker and the users current location is not gotten. The map displays a view over many different countries. After putting Toast messages in every method i realise onLocationChange is not being called, as no Toast appears for this method.

```
import android.Manifest;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Location;
import android.os.Build;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements
        OnMapReadyCallback,
        GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
        GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,
        LocationListener
{

    private GoogleMap mMap;
    private GoogleApiClient googleApiClient;
    private LocationRequest locationRequest;
    private Location lastKnownLocation;
    private Marker userLocationMarker;

    private static final int REQUEST_USER_LOCATION_CODE = 99;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);

        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
        {
            checkPermissions();
        }

        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap)
    {
        // Get the users current location
        mMap = googleMap;

        // Check that the access permissions are granted by the device
        if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
        {
            buildGoogleApiClient();
            mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

        }
    }

    protected synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient()
    {
        googleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .build();

        googleApiClient.connect();
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location)
    {
        lastKnownLocation = location;

        if(userLocationMarker != null)
        {
            // Remove that marker as if marker already exists it is likely wrong
            userLocationMarker.remove();
        }

        // Get users longitude and latitude
        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());

        // Display Marker on users current location
        MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
        markerOptions.position(latLng);
        markerOptions.title("You are Here");
        markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_VIOLET));

        userLocationMarker = mMap.addMarker(markerOptions);

        //Focus map on users current location
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
        mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomBy(1));

        if(googleApiClient != null)
        {
            LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(googleApiClient, this);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle)
    {
        // Update map while user is currently moving
        locationRequest= new LocationRequest();
        locationRequest.setInterval(1100);
        locationRequest.setFastestInterval(1100);
        locationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY);

        if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
        {
            LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(googleApiClient, locationRequest, this);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i)
    {

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult)
    {

    }

    private boolean checkPermissions()
    {
        if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
        {
            if(ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this,Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION))
            {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[] {Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, REQUEST_USER_LOCATION_CODE);
            }
            else
            {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[] {Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, REQUEST_USER_LOCATION_CODE);
            }
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            return true;
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults)
    {
        switch(requestCode)
        {
            case REQUEST_USER_LOCATION_CODE:
                if(grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0]== PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
                {
                    if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
                    {
                        if(googleApiClient == null)
                        {
                            buildGoogleApiClient();
                        }
                        mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Permission Denied", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
        }

    }
}
```

Permissions

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Comment: Do you get any log by onConnectionSuspended or onConnectionFailed?

Comment: Nope I dont, one thing to also not, That if else with the Toast. I added a Toast in the else condition and neither Toast was displayed.

Comment: Can anyone tell me why the onLocationChanged is not called?

Answer (score 1):

In order to display user location you should add:

```java
mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
```

on your onMapReady callback, there's no need to use a LocationRequest.
Be aware that you'll be able to get user position after your app has achieved location permissions. To do so you can follow this [guide](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/location) or use a third party library like [easy permissions](https://github.com/googlesamples/easypermissions)

Comment: I have updated my code to have this, I have updated the code in the question too, however same thing is happening.

Comment: Look in your app settings if you have location permissions for your app, otherwise you'll have to require location permissions at runtime. More info here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/location

Comment: Updated my question to show the permissions that I use.

Comment: It looks like i use the required permissions.

Comment: It's not sufficient to declare the location permissions in your manifest. As I said before, you need to request location permissions at runtime: https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting. By using checkSelfPermission function you're only checking if your app already requested location permissions in the past, you're making the action of requiring permissions

Comment: Code updated in question, When app runs you get the pop up, "Allow application to use your location" after selecting yes I am still stuck at the same problem.

Comment: I think the problem is within the onLocationChanged method as I put in a Toast at each method and this was the only method which did not call the Toast.

Answer (score 1):

After hours of research the answer was in front of me, the location settings were disabled in the phone settings. Witting this so the next person inst as stupid as me.